# Set the ViewState of the parent class in the child class asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an existing portal wherein I have a class which is inheriting from another class. In the base class the `Page.EnableViewstate` has been set to `false` as shown below.

```
Page_Load()
{
Page.EnableViewState=false;
}
```

However in the child class am using Gridview to display certain details from the backend. When the `Page.EnableViewstate=false` in parent page, the gridview doesn't get displayed.

Is there a way to enable the viewstate of the parent class in the child class? I am badly in need of the base class but the Page.`EnableViewState` has to be set to false in that page for some reason. Any help is most valuable!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set viewstate to enabled after the parent class has disabled it - put the following code in the your (child class) page.

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        EnableViewState = true;
    }
```

The order is important - this is immediately *after* the base page has performed it's onload method - we're just setting viewstateenabled to true afterwards

That would enable viewstate just for the current page - all other pages which inherit from the base class would continue to have viewstate disabled.